# How to import source files into google apps script project embedded in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm able to import code into a standalone google apps script by following the [instruction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export#import_projects_to_drive) here, but I got a problem when tried to import code into a script embedded in a spreadsheet for the script didn't have a file id but only a project id.

So how can we know the file id of a script that embedded in a google apps script, so that we can import code into it with its file id?

Comment: Just want to clarify, are you importing code using Google Drive REST API?

Comment: Right. With google drive rest api. @noogui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through the [same link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export#features_and_limitations) you provided, it appears that Container-bound scripts (script embedded in a spreadsheet) cannot be accessed through the Google Drive REST API. It's stated in Features and Limitations, number 6.

An alternative to this would be to use [Appscript Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#development_checklist).